# Perl place oned array into 2D array at a particular column

Tags: arrays, perl, multiple-columns

I have a 2D array.
I can get a given column of it with the following:

```
my @column_zero=map {$_->[0]} @{$twod_array};
```

Then I can manipulate `@column_zero` at will.

But how do I place it back into the two dimensional array?

Comment: Do you operate on rows too?  if not, perhaps you'd be better off swapping your rows and columns in your array, to match Perl's row-major ordering.

Comment: I operate on everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's better to get references to the values instead:

```
my @ref_to_column_zero = map { \($_->[0]) } @{$twod_array};
```

... so you can manipulate these values directly: you just need to remember that there are references stored in this array, so they should be dereferenced. For example:

```
for (@ref_to_column_zero) {
  ${ $_ } *=2;
}
```

If you prefer to use the old approach, you can do this:

```
for (0..$#column_zero) {
  $twod_array->[$_][0] = $column_zero[$_];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TMTOWTDI so

```
do{my $i; $twod_array[$i++][0] = $_ for @column_zero;};
```